# How can I make Doxygen generate a custom URL?

Tags: doxygen

I currently have this as my URL:

```
html/d9/d61/md_ebu_hicad__e_bu__hi_c_a_d__configurator_tool__documentation_pages_2.html
```

I'd like to have this:

```
html/page2
```

One such example is the Doxygen Awesome documentation.

They have for example this: https://jothepro.github.io/doxygen-awesome-css/deprecated.html

This links to `deprecated.html` with a custom link. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Just an fyi you don't need to add [tags in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/1422281).

Comment: You can start by copying https://github.com/jothepro/doxygen-awesome-css/blob/main/Doxyfile to your project.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you have a look at the possibilities of the markdown extension and especially the paragraph about header id attribute (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_header_id)? Please give a small complete example including the settings used which are different from the default settings (i.e the result of `doxygen -d Doxyfile`).

Comment: The mentioned deprecated page is a special case as this is generated by means of the `\deprecated` command.

Comment: @albert, then what about this page? https://jothepro.github.io/doxygen-awesome-css/md_docs_2customization.html

Comment: What do you mean with what about this page?

Answer (score 0):

The file `deprecated.html` is not a custom one at all but the file which Doxygen uses to store the items marked as [`@deprecated`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddeprecated) in.

The following code will cause Doxygen to create a `deprecated.html`:

```cpp
///@deprecated don't use this.
void foo():
```

To tweak the layout of your output directory, play with the
[configuration in your Doxyfile](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_source_browser).

You don't show your Doxyfile but it seems the output could be a little bit more like what you want by setting e.g. the following two options:

```
CREATE_SUBDIRS = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO
```